# WAP Raspberry Pi 3 B+ unstable

Tags: access-point

I've configured my Raspberry Pi 3B+ as a WAP by using its built in wireless network interface.

The WAP shows up as a WiFi network on my Ubuntu 16.04 laptop. I can connect with the credentials and I get an IP provided by the DHCP on the Pi. But within several minutes the connection drops (Ubuntu shows a notification). I can reconnect and get a connection but after a while it gets dropped again...

Why is this happening? Is this "normal" behaviour? Is it overheating? *I had a integrated modem/wifi router from my ISP once and when I was downloading over WiFi at max speed for a while, it would overheat and reboot...*

Comment: check the logs for errors

Comment: What entries should I look out for? Hostapd?